# Extreme Value Theorem - Find the distribution of $M_n$

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, probability-distributions

**This is my problem:**

> Consider an i.i.d sequence of random variables $ X_1, X_2,\ldots,X_n,$ and define 
>   $m_n = 1 - \min(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$. Find the distribution of $ m_n $ in terms of $ F_X $ the CDF of X .

---

**For context, I have solved a similar problem which is shown below:**

Consider an i.i.d sequence of random variables $ X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n,$ and define 
$M_n = \max(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$.

Find the distribution of $ M_n $ in terms of $ F_X $ the CDF of X .

Answer:

\begin{align}
P(M_n \leq x) &= P(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \leq x)
\\&= P(X_1 \leq X_1,\ldots, X_n \leq x)
\\&= P(X_1 \leq x)\ldots P(X_n \leq x)
\\&= F_x(x) \ldots F_x(n)
\\&=(F_x(x))^n
\end{align}

**I am just wondering if i am missing some rule between max() and min() that I could use to solve this problem? or could i use the following**

$$P(\min(X,Y) \leq x) = F_x(x)+ F_y(x) - F_x(x) F_y(x)$$

, but I am not sure how to include that with the 1 - term in the probability function.

Any advice would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your original problem directly:

$$\{m_n\leq x\}=\{1-\min(X_1,\dots,X_n)\leq x\}=\{\min(X_1,\dots,X_n)\geq1-x\}=$$$$\{X_1\geq 1-x\}\cap\dots\cap\{X_n\geq1-x\}$$

On base of independepence we find:$$P(\{X_1\geq 1-x\}\cap\dots\cap\{X_n\geq1-x\})=P(X\geq1-x)^n=(1-P(X<1-x))^n\tag1$$

Here: $$P(X<1-x)=\lim_{z\downarrow x}F_X(1-z)$$ and equals $F_X(1-x)$ if $P(X=1-x)=0$.

In that case you can write the RHS of $(1)$ as: $$(1-F_X(1-x))^n$$